# First argument is not passed to image in kubernetes deployments

Tags: kubernetes

I have a docker image with below entrypoint.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "python3 -m myapp ${*}"]
```

I tried to pass arguments to this image in my kubernetes deployments so that `${*}` is replaced with them, but after checking the logs it seem that the first argument was ignored.
I tried to reproduce the result regardless of image, and applied below pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: postgres # or any image you may like
    command: ["bash -c /bin/echo ${*}"]
    args: 
      - sth
      - serve
      - arg
```

when I check the logs, I just see `serve arg`, and `sth` is completely ignored.
Any idea on what went wrong or what should I do to pass arguments to exec-style entrypoints instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `command` has quoting problems -- you are effectively running `bash -c echo`.

Second, you need to closely read the documentation for the `-c` option (emphasis mine):

> If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from
> the first non-option argument command_string.  If there
> are arguments after the command_string, **the first argument
> is assigned to $0** and any remaining arguments are assigned
> to the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets
> the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error
> messages.

So you want:

```
command: ["bash", "-c", "echo ${*}", "bash"]
```

Given your pod definition, this would set `$0` to `bash`, and then `$1` to `sth`, `$2` to `serve`, and `$3` to `arg`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtleties around using `sh -c` here.  For the examples you show, it's not necessary.  The important things to remember are that [the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are combined together into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) (or, in Kubernetes, `command:` and `args:`), and that `sh -c` generally takes only a single string argument and acts on it.

The examples you show don't use any shell functionality and you can break the commands into their constituent words as YAML list items.

```yaml
command:
  - /bin/echo
  - sth
  - serve
  - arg
```

For the Dockerfile case, there is a pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` to specify a command and `CMD` for its arguments, which parallels Kubernetes's syntax here.  For this to work well, I'd avoid `sh -c` (including the implicit `sh -c` from the [`ENTRYPOINT` shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example)); just provide the first set of words in JSON-array form.

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "myapp"]
```

```yaml
# don't override command:, the image's ENTRYPOINT is right, but do add
args:
  - foo
  - bar
  - baz
```

(If your entrypoint setup is complex enough to require shell operators, it's typically easier to write and debug to move it into a dedicated script and make that script be the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`, rather than trying to figure out `sh -c` semantics and YAML quoting.)